# Is push notification functionality supported in Outlook Add-Ins?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, office-js

I would like to create an Outlook add-in which receives push notifications from a remote server (this server isn't associated with the Exchange Server). Do Outlook add-ins have the API/functionality to support push notifications?